# Entity Framework y nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

Cuando Entity Framework crea por default campos en una tabla de tipo string usa `nvarchar`. Pero tengo entendido que `nvarchar` ocupa mas espacio que un `varchar`. ¿El uso de `nvarchar` puede duplicar el tamaño de una tabla? ¿Es recomendable el `nvarchar` o escoger el `varchar` desde el Fluent API? ¿Estamos hablando de el enfocque code-first?

Comment: En mi experiencia, lo mejor es tú mismo crear el DDL, no dejar que una herramienta lo haga por ti. Ahora, es necesario también entender la diferencia entre `VARCHAR` y `NVARCHAR`, y creo que tu pregunta debería ahondar más a eso.

Comment: En serio no veo por qué esta pregunta está *basada principalmente en opiniones*. Y peor aún: nadie explica por qué.

Comment: Yo prefiero varchar, y si es posible, especificando el tamaño máximo, salvo que se quieran manejar caracteres extendidos ya que ocupa menos. Para especificar varchar debes especificarlo en la propiedad: [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")] public string Campo { get; set;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad nvarchar permite definir caracteres extendidos de `unicode`.

La "N" en NVARCHAR significa uNicode. Esencialmente, NVARCHAR no es más que un VARCHAR que soporta caracteres de dos bytes.  Lo que representara una longitud máxima de 4000 caracteres. Lo que significa tener la capacidad de almacenar caracteres especiales en este tipo de datos.

Resumamos las diferencias:

1. VARCHAR máxima longitud permitida: 8000 caracteres.  NVARCHAR máxima
       longitud permitida: 4000 caracteres.
2. VARCHAR almacena caracteres de un byte de tipo ASCII Extendido. 
   NVARCHAR Capacidad de almacenar caracteres de dos bytes.  Caracteres
       Unicode.
3. Por lo anterior el almacenamiento en disco será el doble en NVARCHAR
   que VARCHAR

Fuente: [Diferencia entre Varchar y Nvarchar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/9807605a-83c0-4c73-818d-a34f096e3b8a/diferencia-entre-varchar-y-nvarchar?forum=sqlserveres)

**>>¿Es recomendable el nvarchar o escoger el varchar desde el Fluent API?**

Depende de que tipo de texto necesitas almacenar, si vas a persistir acentos o la `ñ`, si solo vas a persistir caracteres simple no seria necesario

Comment: Creo que es una buena respuesta, pero caracteres con acentos y `ñ` están perfectamente soportados por `VARCHAR`

Comment: Más bien el `nvarchar` es necesario cuando quieres utilizar verdaderos caracteres unicode como `⾙`

Comment: No entiendo esta parte: *VARCHAR máxima longitud permitida: 8000 caracteres. NVARCHAR máxima longitud permitida: 4000 caracteres.* y luego sigue *VARCHAR almacena caracteres de un byte de tipo ASCII Extendido. NVARCHAR Capacidad de almacenar caracteres de dos bytes. Caracteres Unicode* esto significa que `NVARCHAR` ocupa como máximo 8000 bytes, igual que el máximo soportado por `VARCHAR`, pero tu conclusión (que parece copiada a ciegas, ¿quizás plagio [fuera de simplemente colocar la fuente sin analizarla]?) es *Por lo anterior el almacenamiento en disco será el doble en NVARCHAR que VARCHAR*

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza a ciegas no lo copie, analice la info que proporcionaba y entendi que era valida, o al menos me cerro, no quise simplemente poner el link por eso copie la parte que responde a la pregunta y luego cite la fuente. Claro la conclusion es que el NVARCHAR ocupa mas espacio, reduciendo la capacidad de caracteres que se pueden persistir en el campo